# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException in getView of Adapter class while running the App

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-adapter

I am trying to display rows from my table in SQLite database in custom ListView for that i created an ProductAdapter class . 
I am getting an error while running the App 
Following is the error

```
07-31 14:31:42.548    1968-1968/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sling.freshecomart.ProductAdapter.getView(ProductAdapter.java:54)
```

following is the line `ProductAdapter.java:54`

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
```

ProductAdapter class is

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public ProductAdapter(List<Product> list, Activity a) {
        this.mProductList = list;
        this.activity=a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewItem item;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);

        .......

        } 
    }
}
```

Please help and Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
```

to

```
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
```

becoz `mInflater=null`